# Is there a bug in JavaFX TableView?

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently using a JavaFX `TableView`in an application and experiencing the following strange behaviour:

The resize policy is set to `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY`, and when I start the application, the window is not maximized. However, when I maximize the window, two things happen:

1. The columns do resize, but do not fill the whole space, there is still some space left on the right side.
2. The columns do not line up with the headings anymore.

[image: Columns don't line up]

As soon as I resize one column manually, the layout is adjusted and everything looks as expected - meaning the columns fill the whole space and line up with the headings.

This is the css I apply to the table:

```
.rowWithTopBorder {
    -fx-background-color: #555555, -fx-background ;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 2 0 0 0;
}

.boldRow {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Is there a bug or am doing something wrong?

Comment: do you have css set on the tableview? if so please share it

Comment: This looks like a [known bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8090112)

Comment: I added the css, but the same error occurs without it.

Comment: Yes, this does seem to be a known bug